# Filter Gridview with Tag

Tags: gridview, yii2, tags, jquery-select2

View Code :

```
 [
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'filterType'=>GridView:: FILTER_SELECT2,
        'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Item::find()->orderBy('category')->asArray()->all(), 'name', 'name'),
        'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
            'pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true, 'minimuminputLength' => 3],
        ],
        'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Any Item', 'multiple' => true ],
        'group'=>true,  // enable grouping
        'label' => 'Item',
        'contentOptions' =>
            ['style'=>'max-width: 150px; font-size: 12px;overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'],

    ],
```

That code is work, but the tag value should be item name value that selected from the list, while what i want is i can type anything word for the tag filter/search instead of i should choose value from list.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following code to get a TypeAhead Filter Value in the Grid View:

```
     [
            'attribute' => 'attributeName',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                return$data->attributeName;
            },
            'filter' => Select2::widget([
                'model' => $searchModel,
                'attribute' => 'attributeName',
                'data' => Model::getAllModelListFunction(),
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Select',
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]),
        ],
```

The getAllModelFunction should be of like this:

```
public static function getAllModelFunction()
{
   $data = self::find()->select('id,name')->asArray()->all();
   return ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'title');
}
```

Remember to Install and Use the following widget in Index.php file:

```
  use kartik\select2\Select2;
```

Comment: Where should i put this `public static function getAllModelFunction()
{
   $data = self::find()->select('id,name')->asArray()->all();
   return ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'title');
}` ? on the controller?

Comment: In the respective model